# Safely Undeploying / Redeploying on MERN Stack using PM2 and yarn?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, pm2

I am running a web service on a reasonably standard MERN stack on a Ubuntu server. I am not overly familiar with web deployment or web programming but I have found myself with this project.

The web service has a pretty extensive list of instructions on how to deploy the service, but it has no instructions on how to undeploy / redeploy it. In addition, it was the sellers of the service's code that deployed it on our server.

I have made some minor changes to the code (fixing spelling, removing / adding functionality) and I cannot seem to work out how to safely undeploy or redeploy the service.

The list of instructions for deployment is, essentially:

1. yarn
2. yarn build
3. yarn start:prod
4. pm2 start dist/main.js

Doing this as-is while the old service is running obviously doesn't work as the port that I am trying to relaunch on is being watched. Stopping the pm2 process allowed me to redeploy using the above method but has now caused a 502 Gateway error when I relaunch the process.

What is the safe method to undeploy and / or redeploy a service using this tech stack?

Answer (score 0):

You first may want to have a look around on your ubuntu server.

PM2 is like a service manager. To get a list of running services, run this command.

```
pm2 ls
```

A typical output:

[image: execute pm2 ls]

Typically when you install an update, you just need to restart them.

```
pm2 restart <service-name>
```

e.g. `pm2 restart cache` in my example

Comment: This will however still cause downtime for a brief period of time. If you start the service with `pm2 start dist/main.js -i max` and then you can use `pm2 reload <service_name>` to redeploy with zero-downtime as well. Read more here https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/